# Macro Definitions Syntax

Tags: c

Why don't we put semicolons at the end of macro definitions?

I know that the preprocessor handles these parts of the code. Is there a relation between these two? If yes, what kind?

Is it related to a difference between how the preprocessor handles things differently when compared to the compiler? If yes, what are these differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The macro definitions are just straight-up text replacement, including if you put a semi-colon `;` there. So

```
#define MYVAR 4;
```

if used thusly:

```
for (i=0; i<MYVAR ; i++)
```

would be translated to:

```
for (i=0; i<4; ; i++)
```

Which is erroneous, it would cause a syntax error. Don't be fooled by moments where it could work, or appear to work, without side-effects. For example:

```
int j = MYVAR;
```

translates to:

```
int j = 4;;
```

Which works, but is not a good way to work.

Comment: Also `int j = MYVAR` without the semicolon (macro voodoo) is a bad thing. Don't do it.

Comment: I see. So it prevents flaws in the syntax. Thank you very much.

Comment: @d3l I think my eyes would bug if I ever saw that :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the example given by AntonH

```
#define MAX(a, b) (a > b ? a : b)
int x = MAX(4, 5);
```

If you defined this macro with a semicolon, you could write a statement without a semicolon, which would look quite strange:

```
#define MAX(a, b) (a > b ? a : b);
int x = MAX(4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if we forget about preprocessor, there are lots of places in C language-proper where we don't put a `;` at the end of things. In fact, one can argue that putting a `;` at the end of something is more of an exception than a rule in C. *Declaration* ends in a `;` and *expression statement* ends in a `;` and *jump statements* end in a `;` - that's about it. And almost everywhere when `;` is needed by the language-proper, it is needed for some justifiable grammatical reasons.

What would be the reason to require `;` at the end of macro definitions? I don't see any. That's probably why it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessing directives (`#define`, `#include`, `#if`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, etc.) are not *statements*, so they are not terminated by semicolons; instead, they are terminated by newline characters.  If you want a preprocessing directive to span several source lines, you need to escape the newline character like so:

```
#define FOREACH( n, arg, func )     \
  for( size_t i = 0; i < (n); i++ ) \
  {                                 \
    (func)((arg), i);               \
  }
```

Like the others have said, macro expansion is just dumb text substitution, so if you put a semicolon at the end of a macro definition it will be part of the expansion, which is almost never what you want.